# CSS float issue with out boarder

Tags: html, css

I've set up a grid system with responsive grids, and as I was designing I had a boarder around the div element to see where I was working (I'm a beginner!). When I remove the border, though, all the items now float left colliding into each other. I wanted them to be fixed in their existing columns, though.

I have been toying with float, clear, and overflow, but nothing has worked so far. I like having the float attribute activated for, what I believe is responsiveness, but I wanted everything on the same row as well. Without float, the column contents are vertical.

I appreciate any suggestions! Thanks for your time!

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.row:before,
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.row:after {
  clear: both;
}

.col {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 0 0 1.4%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <span class="col span-1-of-7 type"> </span>
  <span class="col span-2-of-7"> <h3>Content 1</h3></span>
  <span class="col span-1-of-7"> <h3>Content 2</h3></span>
  <span class="col span-1-of-7"> <h3>Content 3</h3></span>
  <span class="col span-1-of-7"> <h3>Content 4</h3></span>
  <span class="col span-1-of-7"> <h3>Content 5</h3></span>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <span class="col span-1-of-7 type">  <i class="ion-ios-book icon-small"></i></span>
  <span class="col span-2-of-7 content"> ipsum dolor sit amet</span>
  <span class="col span-1-of-7 date">ipsum </span>
  <span class="col span-1-of-7 added">ipsum dolor sit amet</span>
  <span class="col span-1-of-7 flag">ipsum </span>
  <span class="col span-1-of-7 active">ipsum </span>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col span-1-of-7 type"></div>
  <span class="col span-2-of-7 creator">
            <span class="ion-ios-add-circle-outline icon-notes"></span> ipsum dolor sit amet</span>
</div>
```

Comment: you should try not to use floats anymore (they were abused for lack of a better way to position things) - now with css3 you should use flex on your rows instead, then you don't need to do hacky things like clear pseudo elements

Comment: Huh...thanks, Pete. Not sure why that worked, but it did and I'll start researching why!

Comment: or simply use css-grid.